# Which of these methods is the correct way to show/hide rows in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

Over the years there must be a dozen ways to show/hide rows or showing/hiding page sections to the client in ASP.NET on the server or through client side methods like JavaScript and I am getting lost on what to do. Here are several of the ways I have used:

- ASP.NET Table, with .Visible True/False on Rows server side
- ASP.NET MultiView - all or nothing kind of control so each row would have to be in a MV. More of a corase grained option IMO.
- HTML table with  tags set to runat="server" to maipulate .Visible True/False on Rows server side either directly or through adding CSS attributes like: `Me.tr1.Attributes("class") = "ShowRows"`
- HTML Table with CSS to show/hide and client side JavaScript to show rows. Gets a little bit more involved when server side results dictate when to show/hide in JS back on client.
- Ajax Control Toolkit controls like Accordian or CollapsiblePanel.
- jQuery with .find() to get to the proper  and then .show()

...and probably many, many more. Most of the time a server-side action dictates for me at least when to show/hide rows in the UI, so I typically lean toward the server side options, but I want to get some input as to which one of these methods is most advantageous and why so I can be more consistient in my approach to doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: As a follow up to this on my own comments, I prefer to do simple client-side manipulation like this whenever possible with JavaScript and even better with the jQuery JS library as opposed to making expensive server trips just to do UI manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you're doing with the hidden/shown fields.

Consider the following when deciding whether to use server or client side:

- Controls hidden server side are never given to the client, so their values are not posted.
- Controls shown/hidden server side require a post back to toggle their visibility.
- Controls hidden client side allow you to show/hide without a post back.

If you're doing nothing else but changing a css class server side, there's no need for a round trip for something that could easily be done client side.

Consider the following when deciding on how to toggle client side:

- jQuery show/hide/toggle methods are great if your are already using jQuery.
- Ajax Control Toolkit controls are great if you want a simple way to show/hide. But if you are already using jQuery, there's no point.
- Toggling css classes (e.g. `class="hidden"`) is very easy to do with vanilla javacript.

But ultimately it comes down to what you want to do with your controls in your particular scenario. There is no definitive answer for every situation.

Comment: I think the fact that "Controls hidden server side are never given to the client, so their values are not posted" is probably the most important deciding factor and will help me dictate going forward. I also wanted to see if there was any glaring "No, don't use ASP tables!" or some response like that which there was not.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single "correct" way to do it.  The correct way depends on what you need to do and the context in which it is being done.  All the different options are there for different scenarios, and which one you choose is the one youa re most comfortable with and/or works best in the current situation.

Answer (score 1):

Just like the others have said, it depends on what your end goal is. For me, it's really about whether or not you need those UI elements on the clientside at all. So, if you might eventually need to re-display those rows to the user you might take the route of setting a css class on the rows, server side, so that they show up initally hidden, but then can be re-displayed thought clientside script at a later time. Or, if they never need to be shown to the user, you can take the .Visible = false route, server side...or to take it step further and myabe those rows should be filtered out of the query that ultimately populates the table.