# How to hide or show a div

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have on my Page_Load registered this

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "clientscript", "document.getElementById('showdiv').style.visibility = 'hidden';", true);
```

But its not getting hidden... My div is as shown below

```
<div id="showdiv">
   <input class="button" type="button" value="OK" name="success_button" id="my button"  onclick="javascript:window.close();" />
   </div>
```

what am I doing wrong?. Thank you for your help

Comment: Try to look to page source what it is realy doing.

Comment: Check this as well for suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572265/which-of-these-methods-is-the-correct-way-to-show-hide-rows-in-asp-net

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I highly recommend doing this simple client side manipulation (show/hode rows controls, etc.) with JavaScript or even more easily with a .js library like jQuery. After you include the jQuery scripts in your application, this is all you need to do to have that DIV be hidden after the page has completed its initialization.

Include this script section at the top of your page or in a referenced .js file if you already have one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 //$(document).ready is used to define a function that is guaranteed to be called only after the DOM has been initialized.
 $(document).ready(function () {
    //Hide the div
    $('#showdiv').hide();
    //conversely do the following to show it again if needed later
    //$('#showdiv').show();
 });

</script>
```

jQuery API documentation on this method:
http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: I recommend hiding the div in the back end code over using javascript. The problem with JS is that the div will be displayed until the page finishes loading, and then the page layout will jump when the div is hidden. Users on fast internet connections probably won't see this, but slower connections, like cellphones, will see the div until the document is fully loaded.

Comment: I disagree - simple DOM manipulation on the server is something we did poorly in the early days of the web. This is exactly what a language like JS allows us to do. It's wasteful and on the contrary making a full server call to do such an operation regardless of internet speed is not a good choice IMO. In fact, move into the world of JS Frameworks and SPAs and nothing like this would remotely even be thought of being done on the server.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use an `asp:Panel` server tag?

Front End:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="ShowDiv">
...
</asp:Panel>
```

Back End:

```
ShowDiv.Visible = false;
```

The `Panel` control will be rendered as a `<div>` at runtime.  This seems cleaner to me than registering a client script.

Comment: I agree with this. This is best practice with asp.net. No reason to inject clientside code to accomplish a simple task the server can handle, especially if you're already on the server side.

Comment: I need to injects it because i need to make the hiding on the OnSuccess of an Ajax call to a asmx service

Comment: @KP I *completely* disagree with your statement. Why in the world would a developer want to make an expensive round trip to the server to do something as menial as hide a row? This is *exactly* what JavaScript is intended to do in this situation - manipulate the client needs without having to go to the server. I know I will still be making server calls, but why have the server preform actions that should be the responsibility of the client side processing.

Comment: @atconway sorry but he already described having to inject the clientside script by calling `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` on the server. What does this mean? It means we're already on a round trip. Why during this round trip that is already happening, would you inject clientside script to hide a div? I completely disagree with your statement. I'm not saying do everything on the server. I'm saying your already ON the server during a round trip in this situation so use it appropriately.

Comment: The problem is (and I am no hypocrite, I used to do this too), as webforms devs we get to server happy to manipulate client-side controls by creating postbacks (syncronous/asyncronous) just to do things that should *not* be done server-side. It's a shift in mindset. The OP could easily do this piece instead client-side and do just the server processing required on the server where it belongs.

Comment: Now we're jumping to conclusions. 1. I'm not saying go server happy as you put it, and 2. Let's not forget he said he's calling this during Page_Load. I hate to say it, but that's going to happen on any initial page load. Using client side script isn't going to miraculously avoid the initial server load. Nowhere does the OP say he/she is invoking a second round trip in order to hide the element. If they were for one it would be in a control event handler or page load checking postback status at minimum (bad). Since they are not - hiding a server-side control is perfectly suitable and viable.

Comment: I just disagree with the statement you made in your original comment: *"This is best practice with asp.net. No reason to inject clientside code to accomplish a simple task the server can handle."* I have been doing ASP.NET for 10 plus years and do not agree with the mentality that this is "best practice" by any means. I think the opposite is true in general.

Answer (score 4):

HTML

```
 <div id="div1" runat="server"></div>
```

C#

```
div1.Visible=false;
```

I think this will work ...

Comment: I think this is the most straightforward, client-friendly solution. The user might need to find the control using Control div1 = (Control)FindControl("div1"); if the control is not coming up in the intellisense to locate it.

Answer (score 2):

you have 2 options

1-Add "runat=server" attribute to your div then from code behind access it and make visibility false or add style to make it invisible.

```
myDiv.Style.Add("display","none");
```

2-Add javascript function to hide it and you could use jquery to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

$('.show_hide').click(function(){
$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
});

});
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="show_hide">Show/hide</a>
<div class="slidingDiv">
Fill this space with really interesting content. 
<a href="#" class="show_hide">hide</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.slidingDiv {
height:300px;
background-color: #99CCFF;
padding:20px;
margin-top:10px;
border-bottom:5px solid #3399FF;
}

.show_hide {
display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for a solution and ended up adding the "runat=server" to my div then hiding it in code-behind with

myDivID.Visible = false;

Answer (score 0):

I think this is another load order problem.

Your script runs as soon as it's loaded. If the page element it's trying to hide isn't loaded into the DOM at the time the script runs, then there's nothing to hide. I believe the registered scripts all go into the top of the page, before the HTML content, so this will always happen.

To get this to work, you would have to put it in a load event listener. See: [Running javascript code on page load, without using the onload tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722687/running-javascript-code-on-page-load-without-using-the-onload-tag)

That said, since you're trying to hide the page element, without condition, you'd probably be just as happy turning this page element off at the server side, either by added a class to the element that your CSS makes hidden, or manipulating its style/visibility directly from the server code.

If there is supposed to be some condition on whether or not the Div is visible, then doing it all in client-side javascript is probably better, so that you don't have to make a server trip just to control visibility.

Answer (score 0):

we create link calling javascript

```
  <p><a href="#" class="show_hide" onclick="recoverDiv();">Mot de passe oublié</a></p>
```

the div to show and hide

```
<div id="divdiv"  runat="server" class="HideMe">
</div>
```

and in javascript add:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function recoverDiv() {
        $('#divdiv').attr('class', 'ShowMeForced');
    }
</script>
```

and in css:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .HideMe { display:none; }
    .ShowMe { display:block; }
    .HideMeForced { display:none !important; }
    .ShowMeForced { display:block !important; }
</style>
```